HP ProLiant DL360 gen8 - Windows Server unable to image
HP ProLiant DL360 gen8 in a test lab. It has an HP Smart Array P420I Controller, with a few arrays configured on it.
I'm attempting to image one of the drives available (can't see all of arrays I configured) with Windows Server 2016 / 2019 / 2022 , and all 3 are throwing an error when I try to select the disk for the OS.
It displays "We couldn't create a new partition or locate an exiting one...."
I ran Diskpart commands (clean, create primary partition, format quick ntfs, active) which has fix other servers that I've had with this same error, but doesn't fix it on this server.
This is the first HP server I've gotten, not sure If i'm missing something in the Array Controller or in the Bios that needs to be checked to?
I'm currently imaging Ubuntu to see if it has the ability to image to the drive to see if it's just a windows iso issue like missing drivers or something.
Thank you for your help!

Please add details on what you tried and what errors you got.

@Zac67 I've tried imaging multiple Windows Server Versions, I've reset the Raid Controller Configuration and rebuilt the Arrays, also reset the BIOS just incase there was something configured.  Wiped all of the Data Drives from the Smart Storage Administrator Boot Screen.
I was able to image one of the drives with Ubuntu and then installed XCP-NG and XOA ontop of it, where I wasn't able to install Windows before on the same drive. XCP-NG can't see the other drives which I have several of them. I have 4 Arrays, and 2 unassigned drives in the HP Smart Storage Administrator.

The error it throws when trying to install Windows Server 2012-2022 is: "We couldn't create a new partition or locate an existing one. For more information see the setup log files" But the log files doesn't say anything specific.

What do you mean by "attempting to image"? What do you mean by "one of the drives available (can't see all of arrays I configured) ". What is the error?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Have you tried loading manually the SAS controller drivers? (by pressing F6)
When booting from an ISO image the controller driver might not be present or might be the wrong ones for the present firmware.
You can get the latest drivers for HP ProLiant DL360 gen8 SAS controller here:
https://support.hpe.com/connect/s/softwaredetails?softwareId=MTX_0edc0d10de0441f18d0886ae74

It failed to load the drivers when I went to load them in Windows Setup. It wasn't able to find any equipment for that driver.  Not sure if there's another way to load this firmware? Like through ILO? or if that isn't compatible with P240i Driver?

Error correction - The controller is actually a P420i not a P240i - Typo on my part.
I did check the version for the P420i and it's running 8.32 which looks like it's the latest firmware version.
